# Azure Service Fabric FabricObjectClosedException

Tags: c#, azure, service-fabric-stateful

I have a stateful service that stores things in a IReliableDictionary. After deployed to local cluster, I restarted the primary node to test the failover, however, after I do that, the code StateManager.GetOrAddAsync>("MyDictionary") throws FabricNotPrimaryException, then in later trials it throws FabricObjectClosedException. What are some of the things that I can check to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

The basic way to troubleshoot errors like this is to catch and log the exception being thrown:

```
try
{
    using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
    {
        await dictionary.AddOrUpdateAsync(tx, dto.Id, dto, (key, _) => dto);
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
    }
}
catch (FabricObjectClosedException ex)
{
    ServiceEventSource.Current.Message(ex.ToString());
    throw; // Pass the exception up as we only log it here.
}
```

However, your problem might be a very simple typo like a missing `[DataContractAttribute]` on a DTO class. In that case it might be easier to simply debug the problem to quickly understand and fix the problem. To do that you should add the `System.Fabric.FabricObjectClosedException` to Visual Studio and then enable "break when thrown" in the debugger:

1. Show the **Exception Settings** window (**Debug** > **Windows** > **Exception Settings**)
2. Select the **Common Language Runtime Exceptions** category in the list of exception categories
3. Click the green **+** (plus) button to add a new exception type
4. Type **System.Fabric.FabricObjectClosedException** in the text box and hit **enter**

When a new exception type is added the **Break When Thrown** check box is already checked.

Next time you execute your application in the debugger the debugger will break when a `FabricObjectClosedException` is thrown and you should be able to understand what went wrong.